# update statement using nested query

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
mytable:
    id
    userID
    logDate
    lastLogDate
```

For every row in that table, I want to update the 'lastLogDate' column to be the max value of logDate on a per user basis...

Conceptually, each user should have a lastLogDate = the value that is returned by:

```
select max(logDate) from mytable group by userID
```

Can somebody help me write the update statement for that?

Comment: How do you plan to keep that information up-to-date? Wouldn't a view / materialized view make more sense?

Comment: The table doesn't get updated, it's created specifically for analysis... Not sure on the database yet, should be fairly standard no? Either hsqldb, postgresql or mssql...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE mytable SET lastLogDate = t.maxDateForUser  
FROM  
(  
    SELECT userid, MAX(logDate) as maxDateForUser  
    FROM mytable  
    GROUP BY userId  
) t  
WHERE mytable.userid = t.userid
```

Comment: @MaksimKniazev, what SQL engine are you using?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.logDate = t2.LatestDate
FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userID, MAX(LogDate) LatestDate
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY userID
) t2 ON t.userID = t2.userID;
```

Comment: I'd go with this for an update, but if the max value of logDate per user changes, I guess that the logDate have to change as well. If so, I would use a trigger to do the job.

Comment: @DaniellePaquette-Harvey - Yes in case you have to user a trigger, and put this query inside it.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, I chose DWright's answer since it is pretty much identical and he posted first.

Comment: @user85116 - It is OK, no problem. Doesn't matter whose answer was accepted, the important thing is that, you got a helpful answers. Thats it. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t know if I understood you correctly. Otherwise be a bit more specific, but from what I get, you should do something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE `mytable`
SET lastLogDate = (SELECT statement goes here)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Yes, that's the basic structure I have envisioned as well, the tricky part is in the stuff that you didn't fill in   :)

Answer (score 4):

```sql
UPDATE mytable mT,
  (SELECT userid,
          MAX(logDate) AS maxDateForUser
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY userId) t
SET mT.lastLogDate = t.maxDateForUser
WHERE mT.userid = t.userid;
```

Answer (score 3):

Following update statement should do what you are looking for

```
update mytable mt set  lastLogDate  = (select max(logDate) from  mytable where userID = mt.userID)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply write a nested query like this

```
    Update  mytable a 
    set 
    a.lastLogDate = (select max(logDate) from mytable b
    where a.id=b.id)
    Where...;
```