# MySQL update from not working - syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains an oldid and an oldparid. I want to update the rows where row.oldpar = otherrow.oldid but I'm having a problem with my query.

```
UPDATE 01_menu_main SET parid = x.newpar
FROM (SELECT oldid, id as newpar FROM 01_menu_main) x
WHERE x.oldid = 01_menu_main.oldpar
```

**The error I'm receiving is this**

[image]

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: You did miss something; `UPDATE ... FROM` is not valid syntax. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: From everything I've read, it's possible to do. I found this answer here and was trying to create a variation of it....although I suppose I'm basing that on everything on the internet being true...lol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881649/update-statement-using-nested-query

Comment: It's a non-standard extension, which some DBMSs implement and some (like MySQL) don't.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh - well that makes much more sense. I'm likely looking at a join then. So much for the easy way out lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join for it

```
update 
    01_menu_main t1
    join 01_menu_main t2 on t2.oldid = t1.oldpar
set
    t1.parid = t2.newpar
```

Comment: This was 100% what I needed. It didn't occur to me that MySQL didn't allow the easy version of this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You had an syntax error. The query should be

```
UPDATE table SET key=value WHERE condition
```

Change the query according to above syntax and let me know.

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE 
    01_menu_main t1
      JOIN
    01_menu_main t2 
      ON 
    t2.oldid = t1.oldpar 
SET
    t1.parid = t2.newpar
```

Check the above code works? You have to use `JOIN` for what you are trying.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow - in my mind I have the key an value. Could you explain a little bit more in depth please.